# How to deploy in tomcat server without making it down

Tags: tomcat, web

I want to deploy my project using tomcat but i don't wish to make it down. That means 0 downtime deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [parallel deployment](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Parallel_deployment).

Note that you have to manually un-deploy the old versions of the web application once the number of sessions goes to zero.

Another option is to use more than one Tomcat server at a time and load-balance between them. Drain one node of the cluster, then upgrade the drained node, then enable that node and repeat the process with the other node.

This is basic stuff.

Comment: I am using session in Php which is used in front end and Servlet for providing the backed services. and graph db Neo4j which is instantiating with tomcat only. Parallel deployment will resolve the problem when there is no dependency on the db. Neo4j is not allowing me to reinstatement it.

Comment: Where are the Neo4j libraries installed in your Tomcat/webapp? Are they at the Tomcat level or in the web application? Perhaps the problem is that the classes are being loaded at too high a level and can't operate separately in two simultaneously-deployed contexts.

Comment: The Neo4j libraries are stored in the webapps/lib folder which is in web application level. I want something like where i could deploy only the changed classes, It should not break the application or crash the server.

Comment: When you use parallel deployment, how does the server crash? Do you get an exception? Does the server power-down? It sounds like you have an application that does not play nicely with high-availability techniques. You'll need to fix that before really doing anything else.

Comment: The parallel deployment resolved my problem, thanks :)